# order by lower have different result in oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to sort label by lower case, but I do not why I have 2 different result ?
[image]

I expect the first result must be like this:

```
1A  
A_Test
Btest
chrismax
Chrismax
T test
Xmax 2014
```

Comment: If you want natural sort, simply remove `lower` from sort condition. What you are currently doing is _cast to lower and then sort_, which leads to unpredictable result on the same strings. `c` < `C`, so it would be as you want without any additional magick.

Comment: Firstly, please provide text rather than pictures. Secondly, once lower-cased `chrismax` and `Chrismax` are identical... there is no way to distinguish between them so the order is random. If you want it to be non-random you need to add another ORDER BY, i.e. `order by lower(label) asc, label asc`

Comment: if I use order by without lower, the second sql has result that Sams and sams, so Why the same order by sql but I have different result ?

Comment: Read the answer by kristianp and the comment by Ben. They explain it quite nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"chrismax" and "Chrismax" lowercased are the same.  The database can order those two rows any way it pleases.